# Java 8 framework for microbenchmarking

Tags: java, frameworks, benchmarking

I would like some suggestions for open-source framworks to do micro-benchmarking in java 8. 
For example, to perform the same tests as with the Golang language.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

> JMH is a Java harness for building, running, and analysing nano/micro/milli/macro benchmarks written in Java and other languages targetting the JVM.